# Do not allow to start kernel32.dll Sleep function

Tags: c#, c++, winapi, dll

I have external dll (C++) and c# console app where I import this dll with

```
[DllImport(DllFileName, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
```

This external dll uses kernel32.dll Sleep function. Is there any possibility to cancel this sleep function or not allow to start it at all? I imagine it something like this

```
System.Threading.Thread.DoNotAllowSleep = true;
```

And whenever is Sleep called it just skip it without interrupting other code.Is there any possibility to achieve what I need?

Comment: Note that "cancelling" a `Sleep(0)` might break reasonable programs. `Sleep` does not just cause a delay, it also relinquishes the time slice. Your `.DoNotAllowSleep` might be better described as `.BreakRandomPrograms`.

Comment: Sounds like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info). What are you really trying to accomplish? And why do you believe, that your proposed solution would help achieving that?

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways of Windows API interception, IAT patching as the easiest one that applicable here.